# What is the purpose of the makeSink method in making IOs for a periphery

Tags: chisel, rocket-chip

I was following some examples of adding peripheries to the rocketchip.
I used the sifive-blocks as reference.

below is an example from their I2C example (I hope it's ok to post it here)

```
case object PeripheryI2CKey extends Field[Seq[I2CParams]]

trait HasPeripheryI2C { this: BaseSubsystem =>
  val i2cNodes =  p(PeripheryI2CKey).map { ps =>
    I2C.attach(I2CAttachParams(ps, pbus, ibus.fromAsync)).ioNode.makeSink()
  }
}

trait HasPeripheryI2CBundle {
  val i2c: Seq[I2CPort]
}

trait HasPeripheryI2CModuleImp extends LazyModuleImp with HasPeripheryI2CBundle {
  val outer: HasPeripheryI2C
  val i2c  = outer.i2cNodes.zipWithIndex.map  { case(n,i) => n.makeIO()(ValName(s"i2c_$i")) }
}
```

I understand the makeIO step which is take a bundle and apply the IO on it, but don't understand the makeSink step.
Why do they do this step , isn't makeIO enough ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert in rocket-chip's Diplomacy, but from glancing at the code, I think `makeIO` and `makeSink` do fundamentally different things.

`makeIO` takes the `BundleBridgeSource` and materializes ports in the Chisel Module implementation for driving that source. There is the same method on `BundleBrigeSink`. I believe this method is the way you take either side of a Bundle bridge and interface with it in the actual Chisel part of the generator (as opposed to the Diplomatic part).

`makeSink` turns a `BundleBridgeSource` into a `BundleBridgeSink`. It doesn't materialize Chisel ports and it stays in Diplomacy world rather than in the Chisel world.

In the example from `I2C` you included, note how the part with `makeSink` is a trait to mix into something that extends `BaseSubsystem`, it's diplomatic. On the other hand, `HasPeripheryI2CModuleImp` which has the `makeIO` extends `LazyModuleImp` which is the Chisel part. One way to think about this is two different "views" of the same thing. Chisel and Diplomacy use different objects, thus `i2cNodes` (diplomatic) vs. `i2c` (Chisel).